# Feynman rule for a vertex with spinorial structure

Tags: quantum-field-theory, lagrangian-formalism, feynman-diagrams, spinors

Consider the interaction term $$\mathcal{L}_{\rm{int}}=-g\bar\psi_1\gamma_\mu\psi_1 \bar\psi_2\gamma^\mu\psi_2,$$ where $\psi_i$ are fermions. I would like to calculate the Feynman rule for the vertex.

Is it equal to $$-\left(i\right)g\gamma_\mu\gamma^\mu=-4ig,$$ or am I missing something about spinorial structure of the vertices?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, where do you get $2\times 2$ from?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform shouldn't $\bar\psi_i$ and $\psi_i$ be distinguishable?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform shouldn't we distinguish $\bar\psi_1$, $\psi_1$, $\bar\psi_2$ and $\psi_2$? Should we have 4 distinguishable particles?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84874/discussion-between-stig-and-accidentalfouriertransform).

Comment: Oh, sorry, you're right. I thought that you only had one particle, my bad! In that case, remove the factors of $2$ from my initial comment.

Comment: More like $-i(\gamma_\mu)_{ab}(\gamma^\mu)_{cd}$ (no matrix multiplication).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform by "no matrix multiplication" do you mean that $\gamma$s will be separately sandwiched between spinors? (And this separation prevents us to contract tensor indices) Sorry, this is the first time I see this kind of stuff

Comment: @VincenzoVentriglia Yes, exactly.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I'm trying to calculate the $\psi_1(p_1)+\psi_2(p_2)\rightarrow\psi_1(p'_1)+\psi_2(p'_2)$ scattering amplitude. At tree level, it's something like $$\propto\left[\bar u(p'_1)\gamma_\mu u(p_1)\right]\left[\bar u(p'_2)\gamma^\mu u(p_2)\right].$$ But now at order $g^2$ I'm a bit confused, I don't know how to handle the $2\times2=4$ gammas.